# How to check if same object exists before inserting another one into database in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

Team.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {

@Id
@Column(name = "team_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 30)
private String leadName;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Email(message = "email must be valid")
private String leadEmail;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Size(max = 30)
private String teamName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
private City city;

@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
private List<Idea> ideas;

@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String organization;

...
}
```

This is JAVA Hibernate class (Spring Boot) and class TeamRepository exists. Before insertion I want to check if the same entry exists in JPA repository (TeamRepository). How it can be done with hibernate annotations? Is it possible at all?

Comment: What do you consider as a same entry?

Comment: As i know in hibernate doesn't have such method.. I think the best approach here mark a column as unique, e.g. email, and after you can check there is a entity with the same email and if yes check the entity to equality with new one using equal method. Also you need to implement equal method as you want.